# find possible nodes On dice value

Tags: java, algorithm

[image]

I want to write a **recursive** algorithm that highlights all **possible nodes** on base of dice value .

How can i do this ? Shouldn't move from null nodes .

In the Image you can see , my current node is **blue** and for example when the dice value is **4** I want to highlight **red** places. I wrote a code like this but doesn't work Thanks in advance

```
f(node n, dice d){

  if(d == 0)
    n.setDest();

  if(Up node != null)
    f(Up node , d-1);

  if(Down node !=null)
    f(Down node, d-1);

  if(Right node != null)
    f(Right node,d-1);

  if(Left node != null)
    f(Left node,d-1);

 }
```

Comment: If `d==0` return from the subroutine - calling `f` with d < 0 isn't going to work.

Comment: Does not work as in does not compile, does not what it is expected to or both?

Comment: What is the output of your code?

Comment: no It works but doesn't have correct answer . i think it calculate extra nodes and should be ignore node which it came. for example if we move from up to down , it shouldn't be calculate up again . it just right, left and down!!!

Comment: Ok. Then keep a list of visited nodes or mark them otherwise or change your datastructure to monodirectionally linked. But **please** follow java naming conventions.

Comment: I tried but I don't have any success. can you give me some 
Pseudo code

Comment: @Fildor Compile? As if OP's code would compile in any language I know.

Comment: @laune I guess this is pseudo code. I asked for naming convention because question is tagged java and for javas even pseudo code is easier to read when naming is java-like.

Comment: @hdiz: Have you tried giving the actual node as a parameter to the recursion and on top of checking the next node for null, compare with that. So if nextNode == paramNode then you know you would go the wrong direction.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a non-recursive solution

```
public class Move {
   private List<Node> steps;
   private int stepsRemaining;
   private Node lastStep;

   public Move(List<Node> steps, int stepsRemaining) {
      this.steps = steps;
      this.stepsRemaining = stepsRemaining;
      this.lastStep = steps.get(steps.size() - 1);
   }

   // getters and setters
}

public List<Node> getOptions(Node node, int steps) {
    LinkedList<Move> stack = new LinkedList<Move>();
    stack.addFirst(new Move(Arrays.asList(node), steps);

    List<Node> options = new ArrayList<Node>();
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        Move currentMove = stack.removeFirst();
        Node lastStep = currentMove.lastStep;
        Node[] childNodes = new Node[] { lastStep.up, lastStep.down, lastStep.left, lastStep.right };
        for (Node childNode : childNodes) {
           // make sure we don't go back on ourselves
           if (childNode != null && !currentMove.steps.contains(childNode)) {
               if (currentMove.stepsRemaining == 1) {
                   options.add(childNode);
                   continue;
               }
               List<Node> childSteps = new ArrayList<Node>(currentNode.steps);
               childSteps.add(childNode);
               stack.addFirst(new Move(childSteps, currentMove.stepsRemaining - 1));
           }
        }
    }
    return options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a visited boolean to your Node class. Then in each if test if the node has been visited yet.

```
if(Up node != null && node.visited != true)
    f(Up node, d - 1)
```

don't forget to reset each time you launch your dice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this die drawing code will help.

```
private void drawSpots(Graphics g, int w, int h, int count) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    switch (count) {
    case 1:
        drawSpot(g, w / 2, h / 2);
        break;
    case 3:
        drawSpot(g, w / 2, h / 2);
        // Fall thru to next case
    case 2:
        drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 4);
        drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
        break;
    case 5:
        drawSpot(g, w / 2, h / 2);
        // Fall thru to next case
    case 4:
        drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 4);
        drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
        drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, h / 4);
        drawSpot(g, w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
        break;
    case 6:
        drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 4);
        drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
        drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, h / 4);
        drawSpot(g, w / 4, 3 * h / 4);
        drawSpot(g, w / 4, h / 2);
        drawSpot(g, 3 * w / 4, h / 2);
        break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, drawing 1 and 6 are separate nodes.  Drawing 3 is a special case of drawing 2.  Drawing 5 is a special case of drawing 4.

It might be possible to arrange the die numbers differently.  Drawing 1, 3, and 5 are similar.  Drawing 2, 4, and 6 are similar as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write any code here, just explain the algorithm.

First of all, you don't need a **recursive** algorithm to solve this problem. You could, of course, implement it in a recursive way, but it would bring no advantages.

That being said, in order to solve the problem you just need to keep track of the intersection node (in case of just one intersection). After that you just need to calculate the distance between the current node - the blue one - and the intersection node, let's call it `d`. Whenever you roll the dice and have a number - let's call it `c` - you can calculate the position of the red nodes in **O(1)** time. In fact you have a distance of `d + c` for the branch where the current node is and `c - d` for the other branches. The only exception is when `d > c` in which case you have only 2 red nodes on the current node's branch and they are in positions `d - c` and `d + c` from the intersection node.

**Pseudo Code**

The following pseudo code considers only a situation as the one shown in the image (1 intersection, 2 directions from non intersection nodes, 2+ directions for intersection nodes). Keep in mind that *the code is not optimized*, it's just shown to illustrate the idea.

```
// currentNode - the node where you start from
// c - the number given by the die
GetNeighbouringNodes(Node currentNode, int c)
{
    Node intersectionNode = null;
    Direction intersectionNodeDirection = Direction.None;

    if(currentNode.numberOfDirections > 2)
    {
        intersectionNode = currentNode;
    }
    else
    {
        intersectionNodeDirection = Direction.Up;

        // the implementation of the getIntersectionNode is not included intentionally
        intersectionNode = getIntersectionNode(currentNode, intersectionNodeDirection);

        if(intersectionNode == null)
        {
            intersectionNodeDirection = Direction.Down;
            intersectionNode = getIntersectionNode(currentNode, intersectionNodeDirection);
        }

        // check in other directions also
    }

    // at this point we have the intersection node
    int d = getDistance(currentNode, intersectionNode);

    List<Node> resultingNodes = new List<Node>();

    if(d > c)
    {
        resultingNodes.add(getDistantNode(from: intersectionNode, distance: d - c, direction: inverseDirectionOf(intersectionNodeDirection)));
        resultingNodes.add(getDistantNode(from: intersectionNode, distance: d + c, direction: inverseDirectionOf(intersectionNodeDirection)));
    }
    else
    {
        resultingNodes.add(getDistantNode(from: intersectionNode, distance: d + c, direction: inverseDirectionOf(intersectionNodeDirection)));

        foreach(otherDirection)
        {
            resultingNodes.add(getDistantNode(from: intersectionNode, distance: c - d, direction: otherDirection)));
        }
    }

    return resultingNodes;
}
```

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: In the image , I showed an example of what I need . In fact all the manhattan distance from current place to dice value is my main purpose. just this path shouldn't move from null nodes to achieve destination.

Comment: Yeah, the answer was based on the image you shared. Obviously you can generalize it for a grid-like structure (with many intersection nodes). In the latter case it makes sense to implement the algorithm in a recursive manner.

Comment: I'll add some pseudo-code later during the day, maybe it becomes more clear.